# How to change the attribute value of svg file

Tags: php, xml-attribute

In samplexml.svg there is a node

```
<image width="744" height="1052" xlink:href="image1.png"/>
```

I need to replace "image1.png" with another value like "image2.png". Please guide me with sample code how to to that.

I could get the attribute value "image1.png". Here is the code:

```
$xdoc = new DomDocument;
$xdoc->Load('samplexml.svg');
$tagName = $xdoc->getElementsByTagName('image')->item(0);
$attribNode = $tagName->getAttributeNode('xlink:href');

echo "Attribute Name  : " . $attribNode->name . "<br/>";
echo "Attribute Value : " . $attribNode->value;
```

Here is samplexml.svg:

```
<svg>
    <g>
        <title>Test title</title>
        <image x="0" y="0" width="744" height="1052" xlink:href="image1.png"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

How do I programmatically change the xlink:href value?

Answer (score 13):

Use [DOMElement::setAttributeNS()](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattributens.php):

```
$xdoc = new DomDocument;
$xdoc->Load('svg.xml');
$tagName = $xdoc->getElementsByTagName('image')->item(0);
$attribNode = $tagName->getAttributeNode('xlink:href');

echo "Attribute Name  : " . $attribNode->name . "<br/>";
echo "Attribute Value : " . $attribNode->value;

$tagName->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', 'image2.png');

echo $xdoc->saveXML();
```